# Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ for Gamma distribution plot

Tags: r, gamma-distribution

I'm trying to plot the pdf distribution of Gamma(alpha=29, beta = 3) on a graph, but I get the error: "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ". Why?

```
x <- seq(0, 1000, by = 1)
y <- dgamma(x, shape = 3, rate = 1/29, scale = 1/rate, log = FALSE)
plot(x, y, xlabel = "x", ylabel = "Gamma(29,3)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are probably ignoring errors. For me, the line

```
y <- dgamma(x, shape = 3, rate = 1/29, scale = 1/rate, log = FALSE)
```

gives the error

> Error in dgamma(length(x), shape = 3, rate = 1/29, scale = 1/rate, log = FALSE) : 
>     object 'rate' not found

so your `y` variable is never set. You must have a left over one from some other code that is a different length than `x`. You should check before plotting by looking at `length(x)` and `length(y). Use

```
y <- dgamma(x, shape = 3, rate = 1/29, log = FALSE)
```

instead. This will use the default value for `rate` which is what you want. Maybe you were looking at the default parameter values for the function? You can't specify names of other parameters when passing values for a parameter when you call a function, you can only do this when you define a function.

Also your `plot()` command returns an error. The parameter names are `xlab=` and `ylab=` and not `xlabel=` and `ylabel=`